# How can I distribute the source code of my project without the imported assets?

Tags: unity, publishing

I have a Unity project that uses some assets that I downloaded for free in the Unity asset store. I would like to make my project open source and distribute its source code in GitHub. But, I do not want to put the assets I downloaded in my GitHub, since they are not mine. Also, these assets take a lot of space in my repository.

Can I arrange my project in such a way that any user who downloads it will be automatically sent to the Unity asset store to download the required assets?

I found that it works well with TextMesh Pro: I can remove the TextMesh Pro folder from my Assets folder, and then when I open the project in Unity, it prompts me to re-import TextMesh Pro, and when the import is done, the game works well. Is it possible to achieve a similar effect with other assets?

Comment: The type of asset and how it's used probably makes a big difference here. Can you give us more details about the specific assets you need to abstract away like this?

Comment: I believe that Text Mesh Pro has quite an unique role in this regard. It is AFAIK the only optional package which has menu entries in Unity before you install it and asks to be installed if you use those menu entries.

Comment: @DMGregory Currently I am interested in assets like this: https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/2d/characters/2d-animated-spaceships-96852 that contain prefabs of objects with animations, or this: https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/3d/vehicles/land/car-20128  containing a 3D model.

Comment: Can you feasibly replace those assets with simple primitives for the version you share?

Comment: @DMGregory Do you mean to replace them with e.g. boxes or spheres? I probably can do it. But then, to restore the original game, the user will have to manually replace each box/sphere with the appropriate prefab, which will take a lot of time.